# ObjC macro ifdef and defined

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, macros

I'm trying to do a macro where if AAA and BBB does not exists. Something like this:

```
#ifdef !AAA && !BBB
#endif
```

or this:

```
#ifndef AAA || BBB
#endif
```

However, Xcode is throwing me errors, so I've tried
`#ifdef !(defined AAA) && !(defined BBB)`
or some other such combinations and it seems like Xcode doesn't seems to understand defined. I'm getting "Macro names must be identifiers" or "Extra tokens at the end of #ifdef directive" errors.

Any idea how I could workaround this problem?

Comment: Try #ifndef #ifndef ... #endif #endif . You can use nested #ifndef.

Comment: Yup this is what I am currently using now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you just use `#if`?

```
#if !defined(AAA) && !defined(BBB)
```

Comment: Doh! I totally forgot about the "#if". My bad.. How silly of me! Now it works, thank you very much for pointing that out!!